# accessing an array from main in a form

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

Hi i am trying write a c# application on visual studio. I have created an array in main which i am trying to access inside a click event on a form but it is telling me the array 'characters' does not exist in the current context. I have tried passing the array to the form but i still have the same problem. Any help would be very appreciated here is my code.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            bool[][] characters = new bool[27][];            // my array characters

            characters[1][0] = true; 

            Application.Run(new Form1());            
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int cs1 = 0,cs2=0;    

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (characters[1][0] == true)     // trying to access member of characters 
            {                                 // array but characters does not
                                              // exist in the current context
                pictureBox28.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two choices: 1. make the variable a static field of `Program`, or 2. Pass the array as a parameter to the constructor of `Form1`.

Comment: Isn't this almost the exact same question from the same PO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870651/accessing-an-instance-in-main-from-a-form

Answer (score 1):

You array is defined inside Main function an is visible in its scope only.

The simplest what you can do is to move array outside the Main:

```
public static bool[][] characters = new bool[27][]; 
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            characters[1][0] = true; 

            Application.Run(new Form1());            


        }

public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Main.characters[1][0] == true)     // trying to access member of characters 
            {                                 // array but characters does not
                                              // exist in the current context
                pictureBox28.Visible = false;
            }            

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your array as a static filed inobject then you can visit it everywhere.
2. pass as a parameter.
3. RPC

Comment: Just list all proposals, if he prefer to :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool[][] characters = new bool[27][];
```

is declared local to `Main` method. hence it can't be visible outside it.

If you want to use it within `Form1`, change to following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool[][] characters = null;
    int cs1 = 0,cs2=0;

    public Form1(bool[][] characters)
    {
        this.characters = characters;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Form `Main`, call as following:

```
Application.Run(new Form1(characters));
```